# How can I globally set a Background Color used in XAML?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have this code:

```
<StackLayout Padding="20"
   HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
   VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
   BackgroundColor="Black" >

<Grid BackgroundColor="Black" >
```

Same thing is repeated in many different places with all specifying the BackgroundColor to be the same.

Is there a way that I can specify this **color** in just one place and then bind or reference that somehow? Something like:

```
<Grid BackgroundColor="{ TheBackgroundColor }" >
```

and then have TheBackgroundColor set in just one file and used globally.

Comment: `<Style TargetType="StackLayout">
<Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="#ff0000" />
</Style>`

Comment: I'm looking for something that will hold the constant used for the color not just how to set a StackLayout background color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define all the colors that you want to use in App.xaml as shown below

```
<ResourceDictionary>
     <Color x:Key="TheBackgroundColor">#2196f3</Color>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Use in XAML like this

```
<Grid BackgroundColor="{StaticResource TheBackgroundColor}">
```

In the code behind use like this

```
Application.Current.Resources["TheBackgroundColor"]
```

And if you want to set multiple values then define a style and use it like said in comment above